# Can two post routes have the same form action url in express nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express

Suppose I have a blog which lets users submit a post
New post page link is /new

Below is the post route logic

```
   //NEW POST LOGIC
router.post("/", function(req, res) {
  var data = {title : req.body.title, image: req.body.image, content: req.body.content};
    Blog.create(data, function(err, blogPost) {
        if(err){
            res.send("error");
        } else {
            res.redirect("/");
        }

    });
});
```

can I create another post route this time for a user login
login page is /login
From action is the same -

```
 router.post("/", function(req, res) {
```

................
});

Would something like this work if not what problem will it cause ?

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 options when it comes to creating routes in express

1 - Creating different HTTP methods for the same route

Example:

```
app.GET('/login',(req,res)=>{ res.send("Get the login page"); });
app.POST('/login',(req,res)=>{ res.send("POST the login page data"); });
```

2 - Creating different HTTP methods for the different routes

Example:

```
app.GET('/profile',(req,res)=>{ res.send("Get the profile page"); });
app.GET('/home',(req,res)=>{ res.send("GET the home page"); });

app.POST('/contact-Form',(req,res)=>{ res.send("POSTthe contact form page"); });
app.POST('/register',(req,res)=>{ res.send("POST the register page data"); });
```

**You CANNOT use the same HTTP method for the same route**.

Example

```
app.GET('/login',(req,res)=>{ res.send("FIRST GET METHOD"); });
app.GET('/login',(req,res)=>{ res.send("SECOND GET METHOD"); });
```

or

```
app.POST('/login',(req,res)=>{ res.send("FIRST POST METHOD"); });
app.POST('/login',(req,res)=>{ res.send("SECOND POST METHOD"); });
```

Hope this helped :)